# Joining tables and making count operation - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have those tables:

```
   Members
   ---------------------------
   MemberID | Name |.....
      1
      2
      3
      4
   ---------------------------

   RentedMovies
   ---------------------------
   MemberID | MovieID | DateOfLease | ReturnDate | .....
     1      |    1    |  2012-12-20 |  2013-01-05
     1      |    2    |  2012-12-15 |  2012-12-30
     1      |    3    |  2012-12-16 |  2013-01-06
     2      |    1    |  2012-12-17 |  2012-12-18
     2      |    4    |  2012-12-18 |  2013-01-05
     3      |    1    |  2012-12-19 |  2013-01-04

   I need to get this:
   --------------------------------------------------------
   MemberID | NumberOfRentedMovies | ReturnData < curdate())
     1      |         3            |      1
     2      |         2            |      1
     3      |         1            |      0
     4      |         0            |      0
   ---------------------------------------------------------
```

And i used next code:

```
   SELECT  Members.MemberID,
    COUNT(rented.MemberID) AS NumberOfRentedMovies,
    COUNT(notTakenBackOnTime.idClana) AS NumberOfMoviesLate
   FROM  Members 
   left JOIN RentedMovies as rented ON  rented.MemberID = Members.MemberID
   left JOIN RentedMovies as notTakenBackOnTime ON notTakenBackOnTime.MemberID
       = Members.MemberID AND notTakenBackOnTime.ReturnDate< CURDATE()
   group by Members.MemberID
```

But it doesnt work corrextly!

And I also tried with this:

```
   SELECT MemberID,my,my2
   FROM Members as mem
   JOIN (SELECT COUNT(* )AS my FROM RentedMovies) b 
      ON b.MemberID = mem.MemberID
   JOIN (SELECT COUNT(* )AS my2 FROM RentedMovies WHERE ReturnDate< CURDATE()) c 
   ON c.MemberID = mem.MemberID
```

But i got some errors!
So the question is how to accomplish right solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. Try this:

```
SELECT  M.MemberID, 
        COUNT(RM.MemberID) NumberOfRentedMovies,
        SUM(CASE WHEN RM.ReturnDate < CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ReturnData 
FROM Members M
LEFT JOIN RentedMovies RM
    ON M.MemberID = RM.MemberID 
GROUP BY M.MemberID
```

Comment: I hope Member 4 doesn't have to pay a large fee for renting NULL that long. ;) Change `*` into something from `RentedMovies`.

Comment: How can i filter result so i get members who rented movie with certain ID?

Comment: I disagree with @AndreKR and like the way Lamak answered it.

Comment: What? Sorry, the OP's example shows clearly that a member that has never rented a movie should have 0 as NumberOfRentedMovies and *not* 1.

Comment: @user1610362 Put `WHERE RM.MovieID = @yourMovieID` before the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Yes, i figured it out, but i dont know how to count results?

Comment: @user1610362 I'm not sure what you are asking, since the same query should be counting the results. If you need further clarification you can ask a follow up question.

Comment: For example if i use WHERE RM.MovieID = @yourMovieID inside query, i want to know how many results will bi generated, because i need to send that info from application server to client before sending data.

Comment: Your code doesnt work well because it shows for members that havent rented movie that they have rented one movie! Check sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee8ed/1

Answer (score 0):

The desired result you showed can be accomplished by:

```
SELECT MemberID,
       COALESCE(COUNT(MovieID), 0) AS NumberOfRentedMovies,
       COALESCE(SUM(ReturnDate < CURDATE()), 0) AS NotYetReturned
FROM Members
LEFT JOIN RentedMovies USING (MemberID)
GROUP BY MemberID
```

See it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a192c/1